# Combine multiple histograms to create 3D-like histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

I've got a 20x65536 matrix `M` filled with integers of the range [0,14].

For each column of `M` I want to create a histogram with 14 bins. In total, I would have 65536 histograms.

Afterward, I would like to combine all of these histograms into one 3d-like histogram, with the x-axis being the 15 bins, the y-axis the 65536 histogram indices and the z-axis the number of the occurences of the corresponding bin.

Comment: You mean 15 bins, right?

Comment: Of course, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
% compute histograms
bins = 0 : 14;
count = hist(M, bins);

% plot as three-dimensional bar plot
bar3(bins, count)
```

However, doing this for a matrix with 65536 columns is not a good idea, since a normal computer screen can show about 2000 *pixels* horizontally. Here is how it looks like for a matrix with 25 columns:

[image]

To make the axis better fit the bin values, use

```
ylim([-1 15])
```

Comment: Thanks for this easy solution. Is it also possible to change x and y-axis (i.e. y-axis are the individual histogram indices while x-axis = [0,14]?

Comment: @PeterRussel The simplest way is to rotate the axes, using e.g. `view([-127.5, 30])`. See also my edit for a prettification.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
surf(histc(M, 0:14, 2))
```

Comment: +1 but I'd use `bar3` rather than `surf`. And shouldn't `,2` be `,1`?

Comment: copied your use of histc into my answer describing use of imagesc, which i think would give better visualizations than op's request.

Comment: `histc` uses the given numbers as bin edges, not bin centers. Since the OP wants histograms of discrete data, using `hist` might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

use imagesc to get a color image, where the color of each (x,y) is the number of counts in that bin for that histogram.

```
Mnew = histc(M,0:14,1);
imagesc(Mnew)
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
```

The last line is just to fix a nuance of imagesc, that it flips the y-axis.